# msg 102 incorrect syntax

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

Below is the drop and create script for my stored procedure.While executing this script on Database i'm getting error

`Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 18
Incorrect syntax near 'Date'.
Msg 105, Level 15, State 1, Line 35
Unclosed quotation mark after the character string '
END
'.`

i tried with adding-removing quotation marks but did not worked.

can anyone tell what i have to do in order to execute the script successfully

```
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[MY_PROC]    Script Date: 9/12/2013 3:31:17 PM ******/
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[MY_PROC]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[MY_PROC]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[MY_PROC]    Script Date: 9/12/2013 3:31:17 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[MY_PROC]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
BEGIN
EXEC dbo.sp_executesql @statement = N'CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MY_PROC]
(@P_Date DateTime=null)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @M_DATE_PARAM DATETIME
    DECLARE @M_PREVIOUS_DATE DATETIME
    DECLARE @M_TODAYS_DATE DATETIME

    IF @P_Date IS NULL
    SET @P_Date=GetDate()

    PRINT 'Date passed as a parameter -' + CAST(@P_Date AS varchar(100))   
      BEGIN TRY
            BEGIN TRANSACTION REIMBURSEMENT_TRN  

                BEGIN                   
                   -- my statements go here which do not cause any error

                END
                 PRINT 'SUCCESS: Procedure Success'
            COMMIT TRANSACTION ;
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            PRINT 'ERROR: Procedure Fail'
            PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE()
            PRINT ERROR_LINE()
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION ;
        END CATCH
        PRINT 'Procedure Complete'
END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should escape single quotation with another quotation
try this one :

```
PRINT ''Date passed as a parameter -'' + CAST(@P_Date AS varchar(100))
```

**EDIT**

By the way you should put an END at the end of your query

Complete code :

```
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[MY_PROC]    Script Date: 9/12/2013 3:31:17 PM ******/
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[MY_PROC]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[MY_PROC]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[MY_PROC]    Script Date: 9/12/2013 3:31:17 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[MY_PROC]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
BEGIN
EXEC dbo.sp_executesql  N'CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MY_PROC]
(@P_Date DateTime=null)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @M_DATE_PARAM DATETIME
    DECLARE @M_PREVIOUS_DATE DATETIME
    DECLARE @M_TODAYS_DATE DATETIME

    IF @P_Date IS NULL
    SET @P_Date=GetDate()

    PRINT ''Date passed as a parameter -'' + CAST(@P_Date AS varchar(100))   
      BEGIN TRY
            BEGIN TRANSACTION REIMBURSEMENT_TRN  

                BEGIN                   
                   -- my statements go here which do not cause any error

                END
                 PRINT ''SUCCESS: Procedure Success''
            COMMIT TRANSACTION ;
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            PRINT ''ERROR: Procedure Fail''
            PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE()
            PRINT ERROR_LINE()
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION ;
        END CATCH
        PRINT ''Procedure Complete''
END'

END
```

Comment: Cant u cast date to varchar as well

Answer (score 0):

[PRINT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176047.aspx) needs *a character string or **Unicode** string constant*

Try to use

```
PRINT N''Date passed as a parameter -''...
```

Also you've missed the final quote after `END` of procedure.

```
EXEC dbo.sp_executesql @statement = N'CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MY_PROC]
(@P_Date DateTime=null)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @M_DATE_PARAM DATETIME
    DECLARE @M_PREVIOUS_DATE DATETIME
    DECLARE @M_TODAYS_DATE DATETIME

    IF @P_Date IS NULL
    SET @P_Date=GetDate()

    PRINT N''Date passed as a parameter -'' + CAST(@P_Date AS varchar(100))   
      BEGIN TRY
            BEGIN TRANSACTION REIMBURSEMENT_TRN  

                BEGIN                   
                   -- my statements go here which do not cause any error

                END
                 PRINT N''SUCCESS: Procedure Success''
            COMMIT TRANSACTION ;
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            PRINT N''ERROR: Procedure Fail''
            PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE()
            PRINT ERROR_LINE()
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION ;
        END CATCH
        PRINT N''Procedure Complete''
END'
```